# Finding contours with periodic array boundaries?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have data which is 2D (theta/phi), and I'm trying to take contours where the map values go to 0. I've been using OpenCV for this, but I need the contours to wrap at the left and right sides (since this is actually the surface of a sphere).

Currently my largest contour is identified as shown below:

[image]

You can see, if you look closely, that it is including the top of the left and right sides and the entire top of the array as part of the contour. Similarly, part of the contour on the right includes the right-hand edge of the data, where I would like it to detect the continuations of this contour on the left that are currently detected as their own smaller contours.

I suspect that this will require my restructuring the data into a formally spherical format, but does anyone know of a contour-finding tool that can either take periodic boundaries into account, or works in spherical coordinates and returns the list and coordinates of the contours? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate your data and generate your contours over the 0-4π domain. You should be able to find a continuous 2π segment where the contour lines align on each edge if your contour generation process is consistent.

Comment: Hi @Woodford, thank you, a colleague had suggested this as well. I thought there might be a tool that could do this without messing with the input, but the simplest answer is often the best! :) I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, having tested this, it does not fix the problem. I'm still getting the same bounding of the top border...

Comment: What top border do you refer?  Please show the result of duplication of the image and point out where the issue is!